# How to adjust the height of the Dropdown control in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular`, `Angular Material` and `css`

I am not able to decrease the height of the `mat-select` Dropdown and the text inside it is not vertically aligned.

```
<mat-select class="frequency-dimensions" formControlName="frequency" (change)="disableSubmitButton=false" disableOptionCentering panelClass="custom-panel-frequency">
  <mat-option value="daily" selected>Daily</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In `styles.scss`

```
.custom-panel-frequency {
  margin: 34px 0px !important;  
  min-width: 100px !important;
}
```

In it's associated `scss`, it is defined as below..

```
.frequency-dimensions {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How to adjust to the height of the Dropdown to approx `33px` and the `Dropdown` aligning to the middle of the text and it's content being vertically aligned?

The `Total` Dropdown should be aligned properly with the date control as in the below picture

[image: Inline]

**EDIT**

When I decrease the height of the Dropdown to `25px`, it comes as below...

[image: Inline Dropdown]

When I play with margins then the `Dropdown Panel` goes away...

Finally I made the `frequency-dimensions` as below...

```
.frequency-dimensions {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}
```

With these changes, it looks large as below.. I just want to decrease the height without disturbing the panel.

[image: Inline Dropdown 3]

I just want to decrease the height to `75%` of the above `Dropdown` without disturbing its panel and it's content vertically aligned properly..

**EDIT 2**

With the new Answer, the `Total` Dropdown is bigger by 25% as below...which is not sync with the height of the Date Control box.

[image: Total Dropdown]

**EDIT 3**
When I decrease the height to `28px`, it comes as below..

[image: Total Dropdown Height]

**EDIT 4**

With the new Answer, the Dropdown displays like below...

[image: Dropdown Height 2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: What type of display I should here so the control is in line with the adjacent text to it and with standard height?

Comment: Just I want the height of the `Dropdown` to be the height of the `Date control`.

Comment: are you wrapping the select inside a mat form field? could you share the wrapping element also?

Comment: I am not using mat form field. I got the solution for this question. I need adjust the font size so that the dropdown will decrease based on the font size. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

try changing the value of `top` to negative values in the below CSS and try to fix the issue! The stackblitz is wrong, but it demonstrates how to adjust the text to fit the container!

```
.frequency-dimensions {
  border: 1px solid black; // you can ignore this one line!
  height: 28px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px !important;
}

.frequency-dimensions .mat-mdc-select-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top:-2px;
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/j4fj2h-fmqlwk?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html)

---

The below CSS seems to do the job! but I used `mat-form-field`, since you have outline in your image!

css

```
.form-field-custom {
  display: flex !important;
  height: 33px !important;
}

.form-field-custom .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
  height: inherit !important;
}

.form-field-custom .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
  height: inherit !important;
  display: flex !important;
}

.form-field-custom .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
}
.frequency-dimensions {
  height: 33px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
}
```

html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field-custom">
  <mat-select
    class="frequency-dimensions"
    formControlName="frequency"
    (change)="disableSubmitButton=false"
    disableOptionCentering
    panelClass="custom-panel-frequency"
  >
    <mat-option value="daily" selected>Daily</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="total">Total</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/j4fj2h?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html)

Comment: Updated the Question with `EDIT 2`. Please check..

Comment: @CPK_2011 Could you adjust the height property of the CSS I provided till you find the ideal value?

Comment: Updated the Question with `EDIT 3`. When I decrease the height to `28px` it is cutting the bottom of the Dropdown Text.

Comment: Updated the Question with `EDIT 4`

Comment: @CPK_2011 please define a width for `frequency-dimensions` in pixels to solve your issue, updated my answer

Comment: Now the `Dropdown` is coming next line. It has to come inline with the text.